# Using odbc, are separate sql_query/2 invocations involving Select guaranteed ACID when followed by a commit

Tags: erlang, odbc

I know that the ODBC library has a commit/2 and commit/3, but I'm not sure if I am interpreting its use correctly.

If I do the following

1. create a session with the {auto_commit, off} attribute
2. and then do a series of separate sql_query/2 SELECT statements (not batched statements, but separate invocations of sql_query/2)
3. followed by a commit/2

Are the selects all done within a single transaction guaranteeing ACID properties?

Comment: with the `{auto_commit,true}` setting, each separate select/update/delete e.t.c. will be committed. If you need ACID properties, then use MySQL Transactions: http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqltutorial/transactions/  when you have all your queries bundled in this way, they will execute as a single transaction (capable of complete success or complete `roll back`).

Comment: @Muzaaya, this is not helpful. My question is about the nature of multiple sql_query invocations followed by a commit. I know what auto_comit, true does. My question is when it is set off and a sequence of transactions are followed by a commit  Can you answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that unixodbc-oracle driver is buggy, i.e. it doesn't set auto_commit attribute properly during creation of connection.
You can apply https://github.com/brb/otp/commit/111f3c091d5f1e9214d2e7cfbd73400b6602a0ed change, which let you to change auto_commit mode after connection is established.

Comment: it might be correct, look at this thread: http://mailman.unixodbc.org/pipermail/unixodbc-support/2007-November/001581.html