# erlang odbc: How to disable autocommit for oracle

Tags: linux, oracle, erlang, odbc

I need to disable autocommit for oracle using erlang odbc module in Linux.
I'm created connection with code:

```
{ok, Con} = odbc:connect("DSN=MyDSN", [{auto_commit, off}, {scrollable_cursors, off}]).
```

Connection was created succesfully. When I'm trying to update a table the request is successfull, but it is commited automaticaly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it could be a setting outside erlang, maybe on the database itself which forces auto-commit.

Comment: No. Using Oracle SQL Developer with the same database I have to commit manually.

Comment: I guess perhaps the issue is in ODBC, not in erlang itself

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833254/using-odbc-are-separate-sql-query-2-invocations-involving-select-guaranteed-aci/12515107#12515107

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have already created a fix myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, guys. I fixed the problem myself. As I said in comments earlier the issue is the Oracle ODBC driver for Linux was ignoring setting autocommit mode during driver initialization before a connection creation. And after a connection has beeen already created the autocommit mode is set rightfully.

I created a fix for C source for erlang odbc module and now it works just right. You can get my patches for Erlang OTP here - https://github.com/RubberCthulhu/erlang-odbc-oracle-fix.

**Update:** The news is belated, but nevertheless it might be useful to inform here about. My fix for Oracle ODBC has been included in Erlang/OTP. So since R16A the problem is not actual and if you need to use ODBC with Oracle just try the latest version of Erlang/OTP. The patches for R14B04-R15B02 are available here - https://github.com/RubberCthulhu/erlang-odbc-oracle-fix .

Answer (score 0):

In ODBC there is [SQLSetConnectAttr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It can be used with 
`SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` and `SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF` values. But I don't know how to call it from Erlang.

Comment: In erlang odbc module you can set autocommit mode only when you are creating connection.

Comment: Maybe you can make this function visible to Erlang by calling `erl_ddll:load_library` with `odbc32.dll` and required functions (at least `SQLSetConnectAttr()`)?

Comment: Maybe it's a way. I managed to find out that such an issue appeared with Oracle ODBC driver for Linux not only with erlang. The problem is the autocommit mode can be set only after connection has been created. The erlang odbc manager passes on the SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT state after loading the driver, but before connecting, maybe Oracle ODBC driver is ignoring it if its before the connect.